# Bar graph starting from zero

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

I have a vector with 11 elements. I want to display the graph as in this picture:
[image]

but my graph starts from first month. How can I make it start from the zeroth month?

Comment: Did you have look at the suggested answers?

Answer (score 2):

You can use both an x and y input argument for `bar`.

```
ax = axes();    
x = 0:11;
bar(x,y);
```

If that doesn't give you the plot you want you can also use the `Xlim`, `XTick`, and `XTickLabel` properties of to control how the x axis looks.

```
set(ax, 'Xlim', [0,11])
set(ax, 'XTick', [0:11])
```

Comment: Or even set(ax, 'XTick', {'january','febuary','march','april','may','june','july','august','october','september','november','december'});

Comment: @tashuhka, No `XTick` has to be numeric. You probably meant `XTickLabel`.